# Split pandas dataframe on boolian using boolian function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function

```
def return_true_false(a,b,c):
    '''
    returns true if stuff, else returns false
    '''
```

I then apply this function to a Dataframe twice to split the dataframe on the result

```
df_True =  df[df.apply(lambda x: return_true_false(x[a],x[b],x[c]),axis=1)]
df_false =  df[df.apply(lambda x: not return_true_false(x[a],x[b],x[c]),axis=1)]
```

However, this does the calculation twice on each row.
My question is, is there a way to split this dataset on a function and only go through the dataset once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, run it once assigning the result (to `mask` for example), then using boolean indexing:

```
mask = df.apply(lambda x: return_true_false(x[a],x[b],x[c]),axis=1)

df_True = df[mask]
df_false = df[~mask]
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems so obvious in hindsight